# Field is empty when using NicEdit TextArea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, richtextbox

I have the following TextArea on a modal form on my site. Everything works fine and if I leave the text area blank upon submitting the form, there is an error displayed.

```
<div class="lineEnter displayNone lineErroRefer"><label></label> <p class="errorField displayNone" id="summaryRefer">This field is required</p></div>
<div class="lineEnter">
    <label>What knowledge, skills or abilities can this person speak to on your behalf?</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="refer_summary" cols=30></textarea>
</div>
```

Now, I would like to format the text in this text area so I am using NicEdit but I can't seem to get it working. I have changed my code like below, but now when I try to submit the form the error that the NicEdit text area is empty is always displayed, even if a value is entered in the text area.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { 
        new nicEditor({buttonList : ['fontSize','bold','italic','underline','strikeThrough','subscript','superscript']}).panelInstance('refer_summary');
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

The NicEdit text area is showing up correctly but I must be missing something...because I cant submit the form now!

Any help is appreciated!

### EDIT:

Found the answer, I just need to get the data from the text are using the content() function of NicEdit rather than just getting the value of the text area. The following worked form me:

```
var content = nicEditors.findEditor('refer_summary').getContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the text that is entered in Nice edit div to update the actual text editor(TextArea) that you have intended to use.

For example:

```
nicEditors.findEditor(this.id).saveContent();
```

this will foce niceeditor to update the temporary content under its dive to whatever textarea it is configures.

```
  $("textarea").each(function () {
                nicEditors.findEditor(this.id).saveContent();
            });
```

For example, for every button click, you want to submit the data to server,

you can write a jquery function like this:
For every button click, save the temporary content from NiceEdit div to the related text areas.

```
$("button").click(function () {
            $("textarea").each(function () {
                nicEditors.findEditor(this.id).saveContent();
            });
        });
```